# SelectListItem properties in view model are not passed back from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have this View Model:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Teléfono")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ciudad")]
    public System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Empresas")]
    public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Empresas { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Perfil")]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Está Vigente")]
    public bool Vigente { get; set; }
}
```

the problem I am having is that when I select something in City and Empresas in the form (they are both SELECT fields), they are not passed to controller in UserViewModel parameter:

```
    public JsonResult EditUser(UserViewModel model)
    {
          .....
    }
```

Only other properties are passed.

What is the right way to manage this?

EDIT:

this is part of the view:

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser", "Account", new { area = "Security" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-label-left", role = "form", novalidate = "novalidate", id = "frmUsuario" }))
            {
                var id = Model == null ? String.Empty : Model.ID;
                <div class="errores col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="display: none">
                    <div class='validation-summary-errors alert alert-danger alert-white rounded' data-valmsg-summary="true">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                        <p>Debe completar los campos marcados en forma correcta.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
                <input type="hidden" value="@id" id="id" name="id" />
                <div class="item col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nombre, new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left", placeholder = "Nombre", required = "required" })
                    <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="item col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left", placeholder = "Login", required = "required" })
                    <span class="fa fa-sign-in form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="item col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                    @{
                        //var requerido = String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) ? "required" : String.Empty;
                        var requerido = Model == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ID);
                        object htmlAttributes = null;
                        if (requerido)
                        {
                            htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left", placeholder = "Contraseña", required = "required" };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left", placeholder = "Contraseña" };
                        }
                    }
                    <!-- Para evitar que los password managers llenen los campos -->
                    <input type="text" id="hidUser" style="display: none" />
                    <!-- Para evitar que los password managers llenen los campos -->
                    <input type="password" id="hidPassword" style="display: none" />

                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, htmlAttributes)
                    <span class="fa fa-key form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="item col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left", placeholder = "E-mail", required = "required" })
                    <span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="item col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left", placeholder = "Teléfono" })
                    <span class="fa fa-phone form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="item col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>()), new { style = "width: 100%" })
                </div>

                <div class="item col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>()), new { style = "width: 100%" })
                </div>

                <div class="item col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Empresas, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>()), new { style = "width: 100%", multiple = "multiple" })
                </div>

                <div class="item col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    Está Vigente
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Vigente, new { @class = "flat" })
                </div>
            }
```

Comment: Can you add your controller and view code to help us understand problem better

Comment: Please share your View too.

Comment: I have added the relevant part of the view, showing the form.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the type of City Property in UserViewModal

```
 public string City { get; set; }
```

Then it will return selected option value to controller for e.g

```
<select
 <option value="1">Delhi </option>
 <option value="2">Surat </option>
</select>
```

if you select Delhi then it will assign value 1 to property

Comment: So I only should pass simple types. I was trying to pass that object because I am using a Select2 jquery plugin and with it, I need to pass also the text in order to select the default value. I think I will need to get the text from database by mean of another property or method when the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder there's show nothing in your dropdown.
In your view model, it should contain at least two properties, such as AvailableCities and City.

```
public List<SelectListItem> AvailableCities { get;set; }
public string City { get;set; }
```

AvailableCities contains all cities which should show in dropdow. And the City is using for getting the value user selected.

In your view,

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, Model.AvailableCities, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

For now, you should see the dropdown shawn and which could get the selected value in your action.

Comment: Hehehe..... your question is valid, however, it is normal the SELECT to be empty at the beginning. This is a Select2 jquery plugin, which populates the drop down upon expanding (via AJAX). This also provides the ability to search for a city inside the list. Finally, I have used simple types and added 2 more properties in the model that retrieves the corresponding entities. That way, it works like a charm.